# barteksc/AndroidPDFViewer hyperlinks not working

Tags: android, pdf, hyperlink, androidpdfviewer

I'm using androidPDFViewer and it works fine, however the hyperlinks in the pdf files are not clickable. How can I fix this?

```
pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    pdfView.fromAsset("magazine"+ magazine +".pdf").enableSwipe(true).enableAnnotationRendering(true).load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 3.0 version, barteksc AndroidPDFViewer handles hyperlinks

Method:

> .linkHandler(DefaultLinkHandler)

for example:

```
pdfViewer.fromFile(file)
                .linkHandler(new DefaultLinkHandler(pdfViewer))
                .load();
```